# java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for MetastoreRelation cnbo, user_profile_g

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

My static DataFrames from Hive are:

```
val pageCategoryDf = sql("select * from cnbo.page_category")
  val userProfileDf = sql("select * from cnbo.user_profile_g")
  val productProfileDf = sql("select * from cnbo.product_profile")
```

`hiveDf` is my Streaming Dataframe from Kafka source. I am performing Joins like below:

```
val joinedDf1 = pageCategoryDf.join(hiveDf, $"pageurl" === $"endpoint","right_outer")

  val joinedDf2 = userProfileDf.join(joinedDf1 ,$"ipaddress"  === $"ip","right_outer")

  val joinedDf3 = productProfileDf.join(joinedDf2, $"producturl" === $"endpoint","right_outer")
```

While running the complete Streaming Query I am getting below error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for
>   MetastoreRelation cnbo, user_profile_g

I am using Spark 2.1.

Comment: Seems to be some problem with the hive metastore you're connecting to. does the table 'cnbo.user_profile_g' exist in the metastore. use sparkSession.catalog.listTables(...)

Comment: Yes, Table exists as I am printing the dataframe after reading from hive.

Comment: It should be a sparkSQL issue. Did you try inverting the order of the DF in the join?

Comment: Yes, these are in inverted orders. The Static DataFrame(from Hive) is on the left side and Streaming DataFrame is on the right.

Comment: I still haven't resolved this. Can anyone of you suggest something how to tackle this issue?